# What is the difference between two duplicate flag options? What is the necessity of these two?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

When I go to the flag any question, I get two options for flagging as duplicate.

#### One is `a duplicate...`:

[image]

#### the other is `duplicate of...`:

[image]

There even no difference in there short description.

From intuition, as far I understand that the first one means "This question is a duplicate question of that question, but this question should not be deleted."

and the second one means, "This question is a duplicate question of that question and this question should be deleted later."

Don't hesitate to correct me if I am wrong.

Now, come to my questions.

1. When should I use which flag? I mean, basic difference with example.
2. What is the necessity of offering two flags? Is not one enough?

Comment: @JoshCaswell Interesting! How could you vote it to close? As far I know, it needs an accepted answer to report as duplicate. Is this rule different for meta?

Comment: It's "upvoted or accepted", but, yes, it does appear that the rule is relaxed for Meta. I didn't even think of it.

Comment: @JoshCaswell Ow, that means if a question has any upvoted answer then it would also be used in reporting duplicate though there is no accepted answer?

Comment: The rule is discussed here: [We should be able to close questions as duplicates of any question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165928)